# Correct format to use regex in MySQL SELECT statement (not within WHERE section)

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to use REGEX (or similar functiuonality) to update an existing table in order to identify if a string field contains a correctly formatted code:

```
UPDATE tblRequests SET flagIsRefCodeOK=(RefCode REGEX '^[A-Z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}$') WHERE DataSetID=11
```

But it doesn't seem to like the statement:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX '^[A-Z0-9]
```

Note, this code will be added to a BEFORE INSERT trigger, which is responsible for updating a number of flags.  I'm not fussed (much) with whether the REGEX is correct, especially within MySQL, I just want it to try to work.  Then I'll figure out the exact REGEX if this doesn't work.

Thnx

Comment: This makes no sense. "Update in order to indentify" Wha..?

Comment: [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) returns just 0 or 1, nothing else.

Comment: @Strawberry apologies, I was replacing certain names for privacy, the first RefCode is a flag, I've now updated the example.  Will check the other comments and update once I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator name is `REGEXP` not `REGEX`, so try:

```
UPDATE tblRequests
    SET flagIsRefCodeOK= (RefCode REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}$')
    WHERE DataSetID=11;
```